# Python dataframe columns fill for the same digit data

Tags: python, pandas, fill

I have a dataframe's column consist of numbers,  I want to have all the numbers at 5 digits, for example 12345 is fine while 345 is not, I want to have 00345 .

How can I fill "0" before the numbers which dont have 5 dijits for all the datas at the same column

columns of df  df["Number"]

I am using pandas or other solutions are fine

I am grateful for your kind reply.